# Access parameter of socket connection object

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, raspberry-pi, serversocket

Im trying to access the object parameter of the client socket. But I don't know how to access it.
here is the code

```
server.listen(1)
clientsock, ClientAddress = server.accept()
print(clientsock)
clientsock[0]  #error
```

here is my error and results.
[I want access these (the highlighted parameters)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx2vW.png)

Can somebody help me to find the solution because I didn't find it yet.

Comment: sorry, I'm new here maybe the details are not much enough. I can provide some more.

Comment: In python you use the dot ('.') operator to access an object's attributes. To get a list of strings containing the names of all an object's attributes, use the `dir` function, as in `attrs = dir(clientsock)`. For example, take a look at `clientsock.type` and `clientsock.family`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, Thank you so much for your help, I called those functions you mentioned above and get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for socket objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-objects) you'll see that you can access the `family`, `type`, and `proto` member variables for the object, along with the `fileno()` member function.

The documentation is always the first place to look.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Nest time I'll read the documentation first.